# KeyError whlie grouping

Tags: pandas

I have a DataFrame (`df`) of size (`1000, 5`). I want to groupby it into 10 equal groups.

First 100 rows should fall into the first group, and so on.

I tried:

```
res = df.groupby(100)
```

`KeyError: 100`

How can I do it guys?

Also, want to get `[1,5,6,7]` groups.

Comment: `res = df.groupby(np.arange(len(df))//(df.shape[0]//10))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
res = df.groupby(np.arange(len(df))//(df.shape[0]//10))
```

To get the first three groups into a df, one option is to slice your original df.

```
n = 3
df.iloc[:(df.shape[0]//10)*n]
```

Another option is to create a dictionary which contains all the groups of your original groupby and join that. This will allow you to specify the groups using `keys`:

```
g = [1,5,6,7]
pd.concat({e:v for e,(k,v) in enumerate(res,1)},keys = g)
```

Comment: I made an edit to make it so group 1 is 1 instead of 0